# Changing A Tasks Title, or Date doesn't change the Tasks modified time - Google Tasks API

Tags: google-api, google-tasks-api

I am trying to troubleshoot why I cannot get changes to Task titles, and dates, from google tasks, based on the query param `updatedMin`:

In the following scenarios, all Changes made to tasks are done in Google Tasks flyout via calendar.google.com or done via the Android Tasks app.

## Fail Scenarios

### Fail Scenario 1:

- I have a Task A in google Tasks with the Title of "foo"
- I have a datetime called `lastSync` = `2022-04-04T04:24:02.773Z`

1. I then change a Task A's title to "bar" at `2022-04-04T04:25:12.773Z` - minute and 10 seconds greater than `lastSync`
2. I then do the following query:

```js
import { google, tasks_v1 } from "googleapis";

const taskClient = google.tasks({ version: "v1", auth: oauth2Client });

 if (list.updated) {
            const updated = GoogleTaskClient.dateFromRfc339(list.updated);
            if (updated > lastSync) {
              const res = await taskClient.tasks.list({
                tasklist: list.id,
                updatedMin: formatRFC3339(lastSync),
                showHidden: true,
                showDeleted: true,
                showCompleted: true,
                maxResults: 100,
              });
}
```

3. and the response has Zero items.

### Fail Scenario 2:

- I have a Task A in google Tasks with the Title of "foo"
- I have a datetime called `lastSync` = `2022-04-04T04:24:02.773Z`

1. I then change Task A's date at `2022-04-04T04:25:12.773Z` - minute and 10 seconds greater than `lastSync`
2. run the query
3. and the response has Zero items.

## Success scenarios

### Success Scenario 1:

- I have a Task A in google Tasks with the Title of "foo"
- I have a datetime called `lastSync` = `2022-04-04T04:24:02.773Z`

1. I then mark Task A as complete at `2022-04-04T04:25:12.773Z` - minute and 10 seconds greater than `lastSync`
2. run the query
3. and the response includes Task A.

### Success Scenario 2:

- I have a Task A in google Tasks with the Title of "foo"
- I have a datetime called `lastSync` = `2022-04-04T04:24:02.773Z`

1. I then change a Task A's title to "bar" at `2022-04-04T04:25:12.773Z` - minute and 10 seconds greater than `lastSync`
2. I then change Task A's date at `2022-04-04T04:25:15.773Z`
3. run the query
4. and the response has Task A with the changes.

### Summary

Changing the status of a Task always results in it being returned by the query, but changes to Date and Title don't appear to work with `updatedMin`.

Is this a known limitation of the task API - if so can you help me with some references.

Comment: Does the same behavior happens with the `Try this API` from the documentation [Method: tasks.list](https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasks/list)?

Comment: That is the API I am using. I have realized my error... Modifying the date or title of a Task doesn't change the modification time of it parent list.

Comment: Does the last comment and the answer mean that this is solved for you? If not instead of creating an answer, please update the question with that information

Comment: @Kessy Thanks for reminding me to mark it as solved. Have to wait a day to do that after posting and I forgot to revisit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my error/ didn't mention this part ‍♂️...

I was only getting tasks from TaskLists that were `updated` after the `lastSync`:

```js
const taskClient = google.tasks({ version: "v1", auth: oauth2Client });

 if (list.updated) {
            const updated = GoogleTaskClient.dateFromRfc339(list.updated);
            if (updated > lastSync) {
              const res = await taskClient.tasks.list({
                tasklist: list.id,
                updatedMin: formatRFC3339(lastSync),
                showHidden: true,
                showDeleted: true,
                showCompleted: true,
                maxResults: 100,
              });
}
```

The `TaskList` object from the API has an `updated` prop - string: Last modification time of the task list (as a RFC 3339 timestamp).

My error comes from thinking that changing the title of a Task or its time would result in a change to the `updated` prop of the parent List, but only changing the status of a task, or deleting a task does that or so it appears (I think it changes when order changes as well). Changes to Title, Description, Time, only cause the respective Task's `update` prop to be updated.

The docs could clarify that what qualifies as a update to a TaskList: https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasklists#TaskList